# Castle Windsor - Value Injection

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

Can Castle Windsor do value injection?

For example, say I have a model object for an Employee with properties I want auto-mapped to an interface describing a View for MVC.

I want a way for Employee.FirstName to be set automatically set to IEmployeeView.FirstName when my model data changes.

Right now I'm using [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/), but I'd like to drop the dependency on the assembly if Windsor can do it.  (I'm already using Windsor for IoC and other AOP stuff)

Comment: I also wanted to comment that I only use ValueInjector for setting properties on a View's interface when data changes.  It's not something that will happen when different services are located by Windsor.  I can post an example of a controller if needed.

Comment: I sometimes don't use ValueInjecter directly but have IBuilder<T> interface and implementations for it, and this all is resolved by Windsor, I use this technique here: http://prodinner.codeplex.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be possible to do it with Windsor (or any other IoC container for that matter), but IoC containers are better suited to manage *services*, not data containers. If you try to manage data like that you will likely fall sooner or later into the service locator trap.

A proper alternative to ValueInjecter is [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I just knew of a facility they had for auto-wiring events: http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/v1rc3/eventwiring/index.html  I thought they might have similar for properties.  AutoMapper is still another assembly, I prefer ValueInjecter since it seems simpler.

Comment: It seems Windsor doesn't have a value injector capability like I need (makes sense b/c it is nothing to do with IoC).  If no one posts in a while, I'll mark you as the answer.

Comment: ValueInjecter is much easier to use than AutoMapper. Way less setup involved. You can customize it as you need, when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out MEF (http://mef.codeplex.com/).  It is built into .NET 4.0.

Comment: I haved used MEF, but was with the understanding it has less features than Castle Windsor.  Does MEF have this "value-injecter" funcationality I need?